# Element appended to the body element is not destroyed during routing in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

check demo link: 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-w7eij5?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdashboard%2Fdashboard.component.html

I have appended "Body content" to the body while navigating through routing the appended element is not destroyed.

How to overcome this.

Answer (score 0):

IF you want to create dynamic Element or adding content inside element You should not use Js or jQuery, it's the way angular intend to do.

For Dom manipulation Angular use Renderer2 service

First inject the Renderer2 service:

```
constructor(public ele: ElementRef, private rend:Renderer2)
```

Then use template variable in your element

```
<h1 #r> Body content </h1>
```

`viewChild` to get the reference of your element

```
@ViewChild('r') ref:ElementRef;
```

Then create or append Data using Renderer2

```
 this.rend.appendChild(this.ref.nativeElement,text);
```

Your example modified check this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-w7eij5-ehqgkz

It will work if you want to about more about Renderer check this https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2:

Answer (score 0):

Use [Routing events](https://angular.io/guide/router#router-events) for delete the element which you were appended before or after routing is done.